# Reading STM32F timer value

Tags: stm32, timer, hal-library, hal

I am trying to implement a hardware timer for STM32F and read the value from it. So far, this is my implementation:

```
static TIM_HandleTypeDef s_TimerInstance = {.Instance = TIM7};

void vConfigureTimerForRunTimeStats()
{
  __TIM7_CLK_ENABLE();;
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&s_TimerInstance);

  while (true)
  {
      __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&s_TimerInstance);
      delay(100);
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Field   '__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&s_TimerInstance)' could not be
>   resolved

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Can you trace back where the field above is defined?

Comment: tracing back takes me to stm32f0xx_hal_tim.h header file, which is included in my include

Comment: When you ask about a particular function in a library, it would be _very_ helpful if you provided a link to that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(__HANDLE__) \
   ((__HANDLE__)->Instance->CNT)
```

Above is defined in `stmf32f0xx_hal_tim.h`, which is probably not enabled or included.
Fix that, or use `TIM7->CNT`.